# How could Goldface have survived?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash*, S05E13, ~45min into the episode: Goldface is electrocuted. A dramatic scene with molten Gold spilling out of his eye sockets. Barry/the Flash stoops down, checking for a pulse, and states, "He's still alive." Given that Gold is an excellent conductor of electricity; and that Goldface was (for purposes of the show) actually "melting" ... how could Goldface possibly still be alive?

p.s. Looking for something more than, "he's alive so he can be in future scenes."

Comment: I totally thought this was a question about The Office.

Comment: His Goldface-ness (?) is his meta-human power, so it might be possible that while the gold in his face melted it still acted as a sort of *Faraday cage* for any vital organs beneath. Dark matter does all kind of weird things after all and it is still a show that basically managed to put an entire episode's worth of story in the time it takes a fusion bomb to finish its explosion.

Comment: The out-of-universe is (most likely) not  *"he's alive so he can be in future scenes."* but *"he's alive because the theme of the episode is Barry proving 'the ends don't justify the means'  so him killing an enemy to protect himself would defeat the purpose"*.

Comment: @Taladris sound like a potential answer